# Magento URL issues

Tags: magento

I am still new to magento but I have been slowly making progress on replicating the production environment to a sandbox environment.

The issue I am currently running into is that when I go to my site I get a long url rather than a short optimized url.  I am guessing it is a configuration setting that I need to change as well as, I went through and had to add index.php to the url string for it to work properly.

What I want to be able to do is use a short url such as /category/page.html rather than catalog/category/view/s/power-tools/id/261/

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i ended up doing and it removed the index file as well.  Part of the issue is that I installed magento in /store/dir/

1) Login to admin section by using the URL

http://domain.com/index.php/admin

2) then go to “System >>  Configuration >>Web >> Search Engines Optimization”
 Use Web Server Rewrites : YES

3) Go to “System >>  Configuration >>Web >>Secure”
Use secure URL Frontend: YES

**** I used the second one ****

4)Then create the .htaccess file under your the magento installed folder.

If the magento installed under document root ( /home/username/public_html) then add follogig rules into .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

and If the magento installed under /shop or directory then add the following rules into ” /home/username/public_html/shop/.htaccess ” file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c >
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /shop/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /shop/index.php [L]
</IfModule >
```

http://www.bestdesigns.co.in/blog/remove-index-php-url-magento

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you need to reindex Catalog URL Rewrites. Go to System->Index Management and reindex. (It's probably best to select all and reindex though just to be sure!)

Comment: I am running magento 1.11, I keep running into issues where the re-indexing starts to hang.  I have done the process of removing the .lock files and then going through the process of deleting the contents in the database.  if I run the reindex through comand line it does not repopulate the database but if i do it through magento it will regenerate the database files, however it will never finish.

Comment: I am running a hosted server on godaddy using centos.  I checked through the different config files and I noticed I have mod_rewrite in the modules folder with in the config directory. Which config file will I need to have it called in?  Or do i have to do a further install?  (please forgive my ignorance)

Answer (score 0):

After working through this, I ended up changing the .htaccess Mage::run() settings.  I ended up having to change some of the base url setting in the core_data_config table to finish getting everything to work correctly.  I also ended up having to set the SEO rewrites (System Config > General > Web > Search Engine Optimization > Use Web Server Rewrites) = No

I found that once index.php was included in the path then my site was working properly.